# Stream request in Python running in Ubuntu does not work, but it does in Windows

Tags: python

I wrote a Python 3.8 trading bot to work with TD ameritrade's API (using the TDA-API wrapper) that runs fine on my Windows laptop, but part of it fails when I'm in Ubuntu and I cannot figure out why.  All of the same libraries are installed.  Getting price history works fine, but trying to stream quotes fails.

```
client = easy_client(
    api_key=config.api_key,
    redirect_uri=config.redirect_uri,
    token_path=config.token_path)
stream_client = StreamClient(client, account_id=config.account_id)
sync def read_stream():
    await stream_client.login()
    await stream_client.quality_of_service(StreamClient.QOSLevel.FAST)
    await stream_client.chart_equity_subs(['SPY'])
    stream_client.add_chart_equity_handler(stream_handler)
    while True:
        await stream_client.handle_message()
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(read_stream())
```

In Ubuntu it seems to have a problem with `await stream_client.login()` and throws error: httpx.HTTPStatusError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://api.tdameritrade.com/v1/userprincipals?apikey=.....

Comment: Do you have the client credentials configured on both machines?

Comment: Yes.  It seems the token isn't being submitted properly when being run under Ubuntu.  Anything I try to run that needs the access key doesn't work (but it all works fine when run in Windows).  I can't figure out why Ubuntu is failing this and have no clue if it's even fixable